# Advanced positioning of Wijmo Dialog

Tags: jquery, wijmo

I am trying to position a Wijmo dialog in a central position,  but I have an horizontal splitter in the middle of my page and this covers a part of my dialog.

I am looking therefore to position the widget in the top center, let's say on the upper central part of the page.

For example I would like to do the following:

- Width: 40%
- Margin-left : 30%
- Margin-right: 30%
- Height: 300px
- Margin top: 20%

How this is done with Wijmo? Is there any library which makes this task easier?

Answer (score 0):

The right solution to correctly position Wijmo object is to place them using JQuery positioning feature, such as the following:

```
  $('#configurationFormSubmissionDialog').wijdialog(
    captionButtons: {
    pin: {visible: false }
    refresh: {visible: false}
    toggle: {visible: false }
    minimize: {visible: false }
    maximize: {visible: false }
    close: {visible: false }
    }
    resizable: false,
    title: "An error has occurred"
    modal: true
    zIndex: 0
    position:
      my: 'center'
      at: 'center'
      of: $('#configuration-tab')
  )
```